# How to remove the thin space between two element in a Column in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am simplifying my complicated case to this simple code to show the problem:

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun TestPreview() {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Black)) {
        Box(Modifier.background(Color.White).fillMaxWidth().height(101.dp))
        Box(Modifier.background(Color.White).fillMaxWidth().height(101.dp))
    }
}
```

In Compose preview, <s>and on some phones</s>, I get the following thin line which is caused by a thin space between the two white boxes:
[image: Thin Line]

I want the two boxes, which have white background, to cover this thin space so the black background doesn't show between them.

Note: If I set the height of the first box to 106 or 95 the thin space will disappear

**Update:**
I found this issue occurs only in Compose Preview, I couldn't reproduce it on physical phone or emulators. So it is a minor issue.

Comment: Specify device name in which you are facing this issue. This works well for most of the devices

Comment: @Megh You are right, I couldn't reproduce it on phones, I updated my question above

Comment: Then try adding `verticalAlignment` to `top` in `Column`.

Comment: @Megh the verticalArrangement for `column` is by default `Arrangement.Top`